# what is expected number of writes while finding maximum in an array?

Tags: algorithm

I have a random access list of positive integers with length N, and I have a variable MAX and I know that the maximum number in my list is M(may not have M in the array but cannot have more than M in it). The algorithm is I have random access to my list, in each access I write the value exist in variable MAX, if and only if it contains a value more than MAX.

Now I am wondering how I can compute the **expected number of writes to variable MAX** with this algorithm?

Hope this example makes it more clear:

```
List: 2 - 5 - 3 - 1 - 9
Read 2 => Max = 2 (1 write)
Read 5 => Max = 5 (2 writes)
Read 3 => Max = 5 (2 writes) (do not write)
Read 1 => Max = 5 (2 writes) (do not write)
Read 9 => Max = 9 (3 writes)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Number of assignments necessary to find the minimum value in an array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735701/number-of-assignments-necessary-to-find-the-minimum-value-in-an-array)

Answer (score 4):

With a uniform distribution the probability that the `n`-th number of the first `n` numbers is the maximum is `1/n`.

This means that the expected number of writes is `1 + 1/2 + 1/3 + 1/4 + 1/5 + .. + 1/N`, which is approximately `ln N` (see: [harmonic series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_%28mathematics%29))

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it makes sens, but I did not understand how you get 1/2, 1/3 and so on. I should add that logically it seams true but what is your x and p(x) in sigma(xp(x)) = E

Comment: This is actually indicator variable analysis, and it's E=sigma(1*p(x)). each write to the variable counts as 1. For the first element you will definitely overwrite max (probablity 1), for the next there is 50% chance (1/2), for the third one 1/3 and so on...

Comment: and how about if N be smaller than M?

Comment: as long as there are diplicates in the list it doesn't matter, beause in that case M doesn't contain *any* information since you know nothing about the other numbers.

Answer (score 0):

Expected number of writes based on your definition varies, depending on the order of your list. Since it s not sorted, if might be up to N (number of elements in the list), this would happen if the list is sorted/ordered. You will have to iterate through all the elements to check if your number is max or not.
Imagine the max number is the last element. Lets say you scan half of the list and find the max, then you dont need any writes. but you dont know the distribution of your list to start with.

if the list is random, you cant possibly know, unless you try all the elements in the list. However an optimization would be if you know the upper bound/max, once you find that number you dont need to scan anymore.

Comment: First of all, I am not trying to find number of read. to find the max of list the number of read is equal to length of the list, but as list generated by random, it is possible that first choice be the maximum(with probability 1/N). So I am talking about the expected value of number of writes

Comment: @mahD like i said, if the list is sorted, how many writes will you have? N. right? and you dont know if the list is sorted or not. and you dont know the distribution of it so you can come up with a probability.

Comment: for sorted list yes, but what is the probability of having a sorted list? and one other thing is that you can access randomly, so it is not compulsory to start with first index.

Comment: accessing randomly doesnt make a difference. you dont know where the max is. so your best bet is to scan from beginning to end. you can possibly know if the list is sorted or not. The probability is probably very very low, depending on the number of elements in the list.

Comment: I am agree with you about scan from begging to end. The number of writes would be equal to N when the list is sorted, but as you know the chance of being a sorted list is clearly very low, so the expected # of writes is strongly smaller than N. but what is it? it's my question

Comment: see @yi_H answer. He has it there.