# Wouldn't this algorithm run in O(m log n)?

Tags: java, algorithm, runtime, big-o, time-complexity

I am working on an interview question from 
 [Glassdoor Software Engineer](http://www.glassdoor.com/Interview/Given-a-list-of-one-million-numbers-how-will-you-find-the-top-n-numbers-from-the-list-in-an-efficient-way-QTN_181196.htm)

The question is

> Given a list of one million numbers, how will you find the   top n numbers from the list in an efficient way

Here is a solution an author gave from same link

1. create a min heap
2. take first n of m elements and place in the heap *(O(n))*
3. for each (m-n) remaining elements, if it is greater than find-min of the heap, insert into heap and delete min. (worst case *O((m-n)log n*) if the list is sorted.

net result is you can do this in *O(n)* memory usage and worst-case *O((m-n)logn)* runtime.

I agree with the author's algorithm and the author's assessment of the space complexity of this algorithm. What I have an issue with is the author's analysis of the runtime for insertion into heap and overall time

For the step "take first n of m elements and place in the heap", wouldn't that run in *O(nlogn)*? At least according to my class notes  [Heap Add](https://courses.cs.washington.edu/courses/cse373/13wi/lectures/02-04/12-pq-heap.pdf), insertion would be *O(logn)* and because you are inserting n elements, the runtime of that whole step would be *O(nlogn)*.

Taking that into consideration, wouldn't the overall runtime  of this entire algorithm be, using big oh addition from [Big Oh Addition](http://www.augustana.ualberta.ca/~hackw/csc210/exhibit/chap04/bigOhRules.html)

```
 O(nlogn + (m-n)logn) = O(mlogn)
```

Comment: Note that in a randomly distributed list, the number of replacements in the heap is very small, which makes actual time closer to O(m). See http://stackoverflow.com/a/28576512/1980909 for details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using that approach to building a heap, yes, but there is an O(n) algorithm for converting an array to a heap.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap for details.

That said, an O(m) time, O(n) memory solution exists for this problem, implemented by e.g. Guava's `Ordering.leastOf`.  One implementation is

- create a buffer, an array of size 2n
- loop through the original array, adding elements to the buffer
- whenever the buffer is full, use an O(n) quickselect to keep only the highest n elements from the buffer and discard the rest.
- use one final quickselect to extract the highest n elements from the buffer

This requires O(m/n) quickselects, each of which take O(n), for O(m) time total.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I'm used to n and k, not m and n here.

Answer (score 2):

> For the step "take first n of m elements and place in the heap", wouldn't that run in O(nlogn)?

Not necessarily. You can create a heap from `n` elements in `O(n)`. See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_heap#Building_a_heap) for how that can be achieved.

So you'd have `O(n + (m - n)log n) = O((m - n)log n) = O(m log n)`. The last step is correct only if `n` is considered to be a constant, otherwise you should keep it as `m - n`, as the author has.

**Followup question:** can you solve the whole problem in `O(m)`?