# While finding maximum, what is the expected interval length in between (k-1)-th and the k-th assignment?

Tags: algorithm, max, probability

```
public void findMax(array) {
  int count = 0;
  int max = INT_MIN;
  int prev_ind = 0;
  for (int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] > max) {
      intv[count] = i-prev_ind
      prev_ind = i
      count++;
      max = array[i];
    }
  }
}
```

The code is taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6735701/number-of-assignments-necessary-to-find-the-minimum-value-in-an-array). The top rated answer tells that the expected value of the variable "count" will be the n-th Harmonic number. My question is:

What is the expected value for intv[k-1] i.e the interval length in between (k-1)-th and the k-th (right inclusive) assignment ?

Comment: What's the distribution of the numbers in the array?

Comment: @Henry...there is no assumption over distribution....but if you feel this assumption will help you to get a primary solution you can proceed....I'll be happy to accept that as a primary solution...thank you!

Comment: Do you want to know the expected interval of the last assignment, or of every assignment? (The last assignment is a lot easier.)